# How do you select specific bits from a Verilog define macro?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

I originally had a 'params_list.v' file where multiple global constraints were listed

```
// params_list.v file

localparam
 parameter1   = 18'h00AB,
 parameter2   = 18'h00CD;
```

The parameters were used in a specific module as shown below

```
// design_main_ORIGINAL.v file

module my_module

`include "params_list.v"

assign reg1 = parameter1[4:0];
assign reg2 = parameter2[4:0];

endmodule
```

The original 'params_list.v' file got divided into multiple header files 'header1.vh', 'header2.vh',

The definition for one of the files is shown below

```
// header1.vh

`ifndef _header1_vh_
`define _header1_vh_

`define param1 18'h00AB
`define param2 18'h00CD

`endif
```

The header files are then included in the main design file (*.v) using the following lines

```
// design_main_NEW.v file

`include “header1.vh”
`include “header2.vh”

module module_xyz(

 assign reg1 = param1[4:0];
 assign reg2 = param2[4:0];

);
endmodule
```

When compile, the following error keeps showing up

** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/my_path/main_module.v(440): near "[": syntax error, unexpected '['.

Would appreciate it if you could please shed some light on what I might be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select a part of a literal, you need to enclose it in a concatenation

```
assign reg1 = {`param1}[4:0];
assign reg2 = {`param2}[4:0];
```

This only works in SystemVerilog. But if `reg1` and `reg2` are already 5-bit variables, there's no need to do any of this. It will automatically be truncated.